# Error: cannot find symbol method canDrawOverlays(Context)

Tags: android, android-build

Sorry if this is a blatantly obvious issue with a resolution.  I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

I'm importing.

```
import android.provider.Settings;
```

And attempting to run the code snippet below in Activities, Application, Broadcast Receivers, etc.  It works fine in the paid version of my app.  When I copy the code out into the free version and paste it in(same machine, same sdk) the compiler goes red.

```
boolean canDrawOverlays;

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
{
    canDrawOverlays = Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: I did several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  Blatantly obvious.  Hopefully this will save someone the time and trouble in the future of this easily overlooked project setting.

- Right click project.
- Goto Module Settings.
- Goto Compile SDK Version.
- Set API Level    as appropriate.  In my case I was at level 19 and needed 23 to get    canDrawOverlays coming through.
- Alternatively open your project's    build.gradle and set compileSdkVersion there.